# Enforcing symmetry in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, symmetry

I am looking for a way to create a neural-network model in Keras for a function, which is symmetric with respect to interchange of its inputs. For simplicity lets assume, that the function of interest depends on two variables `x,y` and returns a scalar `f=f(x,y)`. Furthermore, we know that `f(x,y)=f(y,x)` holds for any `x,y`. What would be the method of choice in order to ensure, that this symmetry is *exactly* reproduced by my Keras neural-network model?

Clearly, I could train the model with symmetrical data but what I am looking for is a way to "hardcode" this symmetry into the model.

I know, this question seems to be really basic. Sorry, if there is an obvious answer to this question which I have overlooked and thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question, it seems that what you are looking for is a convenient way to have a layer or a set of layers, with shared weights, applied to the inputs in both forward and reverse order.

i.e. similar to how a convolution identifies a pattern through a set of time steps but considering the input buffer to be circular.

A convenient way to achieve this would be to put your special 'convolution' layer inside a reusable aux model and then max pool the results. Something like the following:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

def make_inner_model():
  inp = Input(shape=(2,))
  h1 = Dense(8, activation='relu')(inp)
  out = Dense(1)(h1)
  model = Model(inp, out)
  return model

def make_model(inner_model):
  inp = Input(shape=(2,))
  rev = Lambda(lambda x: K.concatenate([x[:, 1:], x[:, 0:1]], axis=1))(inp)
  r1 = inner_model(inp)
  r2 = inner_model(rev)
  out = Maximum()([r1, r2])
  model = Model(inp, out)
  model.compile('adam', 'mse')
  return model

inner = make_inner_model()
model = make_model(inner)
model.summary()
```

Comment: Do you have some links or papers on this topic?

Comment: I'm confused by the max-pooling here.  How does it enforce that the weights are the same?